# Reading an already open workbook in visual basic (on visual studio)

Tags: visual-studio

I work on a VB project and use Visual Studio 2015 after a switch from VBA to VB. I need to read some information from an Excel Workbook. Since this file might have already been opened, I do not want to open it again, so structure of my script is as follows:

(Function) Check that the file is open ( "works perfectly")

If it is open ("Problematic")

- Access the file
- Activate a specific sheet
- Read information

Else (the file is not open)----("works perfectly")

- Open the file
- Activate a specific sheet
- Read information

End if

In this structure, I have already spent three days for the first part but any script that I found on the Internet did not work in my project. Many people claim that given script works, however, I got an error on line 12 because oWB equals "Nothing" on line 11.

I could not figure out what the problem is. Simply, I need an assignment like that (this works only in VBA):

```
Set oWB=Workbooks("sample.xlsx")
```

And, my whole script is following:

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop

Module Module1

Sub ReadInformation() 'Line 1
 Dim oXL As Excel.Application
 Dim oWB As Excel.Workbook
 Dim oWS As Excel.Worksheet
 Dim filepath2 As String 'Line 5

 filepath2 = "C:\Users\IEN 271\Desktop\sample.xlsx" 

 If FileInUse(filepath2) Then
  oXL = New Excel.Application
  oXL = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
  oXL.Visible = True
  oWB = oXL.ActiveWorkbook 'Line 11
  oWS = oWB.Worksheets("sampleSheet")
  oWS.Activate()
 Else
  oXL = New Excel.Application
  oXL.Visible = True
  oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\IEN 271\Desktop\sample.xlsx", [ReadOnly]:=False)    
  oWS = oWB.Worksheets("sampleSheet")
  oWS.Activate()
 End If

 'Script for reading process (fine)
End Sub

End Module
```

Any help would be a lot appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending hours, I just figured it out. Here it is the correct version of script:

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Module Module1

Sub ReadInformation() 'Line 1
  Dim oXL As Excel.Application
  Dim oWB As Excel.Workbook
  Dim oWS As Excel.Worksheet
  Dim filepath2 As String 'Line 5

  filepath2 = "C:\Users\IEN 271\Desktop\sample.xlsx" 

  If FileInUse(filepath2) Then
   oXL = New Excel.Application
   oXL = CType(System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application"), Excel.Application)
   oWB = GetObject("C:\Users\IEN 271\Desktop\sample.xlsx")      
   oWS = oWB.Worksheets("sampleSheet")
   oWS.Activate()
  Else
   oXL = New Excel.Application
   oXL.Visible = True
   oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\IEN 271\Desktop\sample.xlsx", [ReadOnly]:=False)    
   oWS = oWB.Worksheets("sampleSheet")
   oWS.Activate()
  End If

 'Script for reading process (fine)
End Sub
```

This allows getting a .xlsx file by name in case of there are multiple "Excel worksbooks" already open. Hope to be helpful someone else!

Answer (score 1):

```
set wb = GetObject("c:\file.xls")
```

is all you need to do. Doesn't matter if open or not.

So use the document object, as you should be, not the App object.

Comment: No Noodles. This line works in VBA but not in VB script. Set assignment is not supported in VB script. I need an equivalent of this line in VB script. Thanks.

Comment: @Yusuf - ``Set`` is very much part of VBScript - see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4afksd44%28v=vs.84%29.aspx for evidence.

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner- When I put the line suggested by Noodles above, I got this warning: <"Let" and "Set" assignment statements are no longer supported>. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner - I made a mistake in the first comment. I code on Visual Basic not VB script. I always use "set" command in VBA, but it is not a valid command in Visual Basic 2015.

Comment: @Yusuf - so please edit/update the language tag of your question.